# Need to adjust condition to say if I'm pulling categories from a post, to pull only the first one

Tags: php, categories, conditional-tags

I have a condition to pull posts based on category so when in my single.php users can see related posts based on categories, but the problem here is if someone posts a post with more than one category, it begins to break the site visually.

How can I adjust my code to say pull only the first category. Or, even if it reads two categories to just show two posts.

Right now it only pulls two, but once a second category is added it adds that too.

This is the code:

```
<?php
    if ( is_single()) {
        $categories = get_the_category();
        if ($categories) {
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            $cat = $category->cat_ID;
            $args=array(
            'cat' => $cat,
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
            'posts_per_page'=>2,
            'caller_get_posts'=>1
        );
            $my_query = null;
            $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
                if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {

        while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); 
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are looping through the array of categories retrieved with `get_the_category()` and for each category you retrieve two posts. In stead I understand you want to pull two posts from one category only.

To do so, you would have to remove the `foreach` loop and in stead define `$category` as the first category in the array only, like this: `$category = $categories[0];`

Comment: It works! But just to be clear, and to make sure I'm doing this right, I'm swapping `foreach ($categories as $category)` for `$category = $categories[0];` correct?

Comment: How smart could we make this, could we if in the first category, if there is only one post, to grab one from the second category?

Comment: Yes, that's the way. Of course you can make it smarter. Theoretically, you would have to take into account that there are no posts at all in the first two categories. You would have to add a counter which goes up every time you find a post and loop through all categories until you have found two posts.